# FindAll documents that has an array of sub-documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Following is an example model:

```
UserModel == {
    name: String,
    friends: [ObjectId],
}
```

friends corresponds to a list of id of objects of some other model for example AboutModel.

```
AboutModel == {
    name: String,
}
```

Is it possible to find all `Users` who have a friend with `_id="1234"` in `friends` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user.find({friends: {$in: ['1234']}})
```